# R code debugging and error correction understanding

Tags: r, function, debugging, error-handling

I have this code iv written for counting that reads a directory full of files and reports the number of completely observed cases in each data file. The function should return a data frame where the first column is the name of the file and the second column is the number of complete cases. I need help in the error in this code which is:

> Error in [.data.frame(data, i) : undefined columns selected
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In comp[i] <- !is.na(data[i]) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   2: In comp[i] <- !is.na(data[i]) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   3: In comp[i] <- !is.na(data[i]) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

The code is the following:

```
complete<-function(directory, id=1:332){
        files.list<-list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE, pattern=".csv") 
        comp<-character()
        return.data<-data.frame()
        nobs<-numeric()

        for(i in id){
         data<-read.csv(files.list[i])
            comp[i]<-!is.na(data[i])
            nobs[i]<-nrow(comp[i])

    }
        return.data<-c(id,nobs)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that `!is.na()` returns a boolean vector and not a single value, you cannot insert multiple elements into the single element `comp[i]`.

In `R` there is a function `complete.cases` which does exactly what you attempted. With this your function would look like this

```
complete<-function(directory, id=1:332){
  files.list<-list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE, pattern=".csv") 
  nobs <- numeric(length(id))
  for(i in id){
    data<-read.csv(files.list[i])
    nobs[i]<-sum(complete.cases(data))
  }
  return.data<-data.frame(id,nobs)
}
```

That aside your code has several flaws I want to point out

- why is `comp` of type `character`?
- allocate the size of a vector if you know it beforehand (`nobs <- numeric(length(id))`)
- do you really want to check only column`i` of your `i`th loaded data.frame` for missing values?
- if you assign `return.data <- c(id,nobs)` `return.data` will be a single numeric vector with `ids` at the beginning and `nobs` at the end.

Comment: Thanks wici for the clarifications. I'm a newbie and these are the mistakes im tring to figure out and understand for fundamentals clarity. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide an index to your data.. so that it selects all rows and i column.e.g
comp[i]<-!is.na(data[ ,i])

Comment: But even after indexing it's giving across error:Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , i) : undefined columns selected

Comment: try this:  comp[[i]]<-data[!is.na(data$colum2), ]          

instead of colum2 define your column name... its hard to fix code like this without data- so it's best to put a reproducable example

Comment: appreciate the help, but what i'm trying to achieve is to get the values from ith value datafile onto comp[[i]]. Here's the data link,  https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip